# How to fix Datatables language plugin not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i have a Datatable language plugin that simply doesn't work for no obvious reason, i'm trying to get my datatable to be in French (sorting text, search bar, pagination etc..) i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
this is my jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#id').DataTable({
    "language": {
       "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/French.json"
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last working version of that json seems to be 1.10.16.

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#id').DataTable({
        
    language: {
       url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/French.json"
    }
    
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="id">
    <thead>
        <th>colonne 1</th>
        <th>colonne 2</th>
        <th>colonne 3</th>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, datatables.net gave that plugin url instead
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/French

Comment: Lol... I just notice I answered in french :D

Comment: Haha pas de souci :P

Comment: I know... Datatables website is wrong. I think it should be reported...

Comment: Will report it immediately